# Setting up Proxy Settings on Debian

Tags: debian, proxy, http-proxy

During installation of Debian I was asked for a Standard Proxy String in the form of `http://user:password@host:port/`, which I entered. apt-get ran and retrieved files during update, and now Debian is installed. However, when I tried running `sudo apt-get install ...`, I get an error message containing the message `Could not resolve proxy_host` where `proxy_host` is the host I entered during installation.

Are there other places where I have to set up the proxy information?

Comment: 'Could not resolve' sounds more like a DNS or general networking problem.  Can you resolve (and access, ping) the proxy host?

Comment: How do I test that? Everything worked fine during installation. -- Just read the ping part...

Comment: @sr_ I'm not able to ping the proxy host.

Comment: Your network settings might be incorrect, then.  Have a look at the [Debian Handbook's section on network configuration](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.config-network.html).  (You could also be missing some [firmware](http://wiki.debian.org/Firmware/) for your NIC.)

Comment: How does your machine get internet access? Post the output of `ifconfig` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`. Replace private information by placeholders if you like, but consistently (always the same placeholder for the same piece of information).

Answer (score 9):

The following is for general proxy, apt and wget and you can remove the `user:password@` for a proxy that doesn't require it:

For General proxy:

```
touch /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
```

add the following:

```
export ftp_proxy=ftp://user:password@host:port
export http_proxy=http://user:password@host:port
export https_proxy=https://user:password@host:port
export socks_proxy=https://user:password@host:port
```

For APT proxy:

```
touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99HttpProxy
```

add the following:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@host:port";
```

For wget:

```
nano /etc/wgetrc
```

find and uncomment proxy lines or add them if not present

```
http_proxy = http://user:password@host:port
https_proxy = ...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The http proxy information, entered during the set up, should (normally) end up in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf`

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@host:port/";
```

Comment: It should be two colons `::` between `http` and `Proxy`

Answer (score -1):

Edit the bash.bashrc file and add the following lines to the bottom of the file:

```
export ftp_proxy="ftp://user:password@proxyIP:port"
export http_proxy="http://user:password@proxyIP:port"
export https_proxy="https://user:password@proxyIP:port"
export socks_proxy="https://user:password@proxyIP:port"
```